# Standalone application with Petrel and Ocean

Tags: ocean, petrel

So I am a n00b with the Petrel platform and Ocean SDK. I want to create a standalone application (not a plugin!) that consumes the Ocean SDK to interact with the Petrel projects. One way, I could think of was to create a plug-in that interacts with the app via IPC but is there any other approach that has absolutely no plugin in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Great to see that you are interested in Petrel and Ocean. Developing standalone applications is not permitted under the Ocean Software Development Framework license agreement. All products developed using the framework must be hosted by Petrel, i.e., they must be plug-ins. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: That's what I thought, Horacio. Thanks for the confirmation =)

Answer (score 0):

Ocean for Studio API is your solution.
You could develop stand-alone application if you have license to expose your data stored in Petrel Studio. Also, you could call petrel projects function and do something on them.