# How to run simulation case using "ocean petrel API" from console application in C#

Tags: ocean, petrel

I found these links similar to my question. But they are run as part of the plugin.

[Standalone application with Petrel and Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338289/standalone-application-with-petrel-and-ocean)

[How to run a simulation case using CaseRunner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653102/how-to-run-a-simulation-case-using-caserunner-function)

My requirement is to call Ocean Petrel API to run eclipse and get the results back to in my application.

Does anybody have any idea?

I have checked this link but this is running as part of the plugin, not outside the Petrel.

I have tried the following code. I am getting null reference exception at SimulationRoot simroot = SimulationRoot.Get(PetrelProject.PrimaryProject);

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Case MyTest;
                CustomCaseRunnerMonitor monit5 = new CustomCaseRunnerMonitor();
                SimulationRoot simroot = SimulationRoot.Get(PetrelProject.PrimaryProject);

                using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction())
                {
                    trans.Lock(simroot);
                    MyTest = simroot.Cases.FirstOrDefault();

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                CaseRunner cRun = SimulationSystem.GetCaseRunner(MyTest);
                cRun.Export();
                cRun.Run(monit5);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString()); 
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }

    public class CustomCaseRunnerMonitor : CaseRunnerMonitor
    {
        //...
        public override void RunCompleted()
        {
            PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("CustomCaseRunnerMonitor is completed!");
        }

        public override void RunAborted()
        {
            PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("CustomCaseRunnerMonitor is abroted!");
        }

        public override void SimulationProgressChanged(int progress)
        {
            PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("SimulationProgressChanged: " + progress);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you tried.

Comment: @vivekacarya I don't think you shared any code. Where is it?

Comment: Just updated it now

Comment: Thanks, that will help others to help you.

Comment: I want to create a console application to run an eclispe simulation and get back the simulation results.

Comment: Why not just launch ECLIPSE directly? Do you already have a case or do you want your console application to also export from Petrel?

Comment: This is some other application I am building that need reservoir results, so I want to run the scenario in the background(not manually) using Ocean API for Petrel . I do not have Ocean API for Eclipse.